# Find All real $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that satisfies the conditions as stated in the question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

> Question:   A curve $y=f(x)$ of the differential equation $y''-4y'-5y=0$ intersect at origin to the curve $y=g(x)$ of the differential equation $y''+5y'-6y=0$. Find all real $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that they have same slope at origin and $\lim_{x\to \infty} {(g(x))^5 \over f(x)}={6\over 7} $.

My Attempt:

> With the given data I firstly solved the given second order ordinary differential equations for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively. After solving we get $f(x)=C_1 e^{-x}+C_2 e^{5x}$ and $g(x)=C_3e^{x}+C_4e^{-6x}$. Now given that $f(x)$ intersect $g(x)$ at the origin, therefore we get $f(0)=g(0)\implies C_1+C_2=C_3 +C_4 $  $(1)$.

> Also the second half tells us that they have the same slope at origin. Assume that slope of $f(x)$ is $ m_1$ and slope of $g(x)$ is $m_2$, consequently we get $m_1=f'(x)=-C_1e^{-x}+5C_2e^{5x}$ and $m_2=g'(x)=C_3 e^{x}-6 C_4e^{-6x}$. Again at origin they have same values so we get $f'(0)=g'(0)$ ( at origin $m_1=m_2$). We get $-C_1+5C_2 =C_3-6C_4$ $(2)$.

The last given condition (of limit) I am confused whether I should get the values of $f(x) $ and $g(x)$ be reduced to coefficients $C_1 $ and $C_2$ only (i.e. getting the values of $C_3$ and $C_4$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$, even the calculations have become somewhat difficult. I think I have missed something here.

Any Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {g(x)^{5}}  {f(x)} \to \frac {C_3^{5}} {C_2}$. So $C_2=\frac  7  6C_3^{5}$. You have to solve (1), (2) and the equation  $C_2=\frac  7  6C_3^{5}$ to find all possible values of the coefficients.

[I don't think there is  a neat answer, but you can just state the three conditions on the coefficients].

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have done is absolutely correct.
The last condition gives: $C_2 = \frac{7}{6} * C_3^5$.
Now, you have 4 variables and 3 equations, therefore $f(x)$ and $ g(x)$ can be expressed in terms of a single variable, which will represent the set of all $f(x)'s$ and $ g(x)'s$ that satisfy the given condition.